# Save Javascript ArrayBuffer as BLOB in SQLite

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I have large text which i want to save as BLOB in SQLite DB. I learned in other posts that the string needs to be converted into ByteArray before being saved as BLOB. Below is my function that converts string into ByteArray But when inserting this ArrayBuffer into DB,its being saved as Object string `[object ArrayBuffer]`. That is because I am assuming Javascript ArrayBuffer is incompatible with SQLite. Can you help me as to how can I store this ArrayBuffer as BLOB without it being getting converted to string?

```
function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bufView;
}
```

Comment: Why a blob and not a string?

Comment: My string is very large and when i save it as TEXT, it gives me null when i fetch it.

Comment: `TEXT` is not limited by SQLite, so I think there's something else going on.

Comment: Check the limits on [DOCS](https://sqlite.org/limits.html) - Maximum length of a string or BLOB section. Maybe that limit is set lower or maybe your text has more than the default limit of 1GB of text :)

Comment: Also, the docs imply that if you can't write a string that big, you're also not going to be able to write a blob that big.